# Designing views/windows in Mac OSX first time

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview, nswindow

I am about to tackle my first Mac OSX project after developing for iOS.
In my iOS applications, it is clear to me the whole NavigationViewController->MyViewController->MyViews paradigm.

A bit more background on the iOS app so it would be easier to understand me:
The application is some sort of graphic viewer. Once you login you have a list of drawings, and if you select one, it opens it up. 
Now in the iOS app I have a custom UIViewController that have some menu UI and a UIScrollView that holds a UIView in which I draw the drawing.
The custom UIViewController is responsible for acting as the "application" where the UIView inside is merely a graphic context.

Now - back to Mac:
I was thinking that my main window would show the drawings and once one is selected,
I would add another window with an NSView that is the graphic context of the drawing,
and the window will be acting as the UIViewController in the iOS app.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have `NSViewController` or `NSWindowController` on the Mac, to put your controller logic in. If you're going for separate windows, subclassing `NSWindowController` would make sense.

Comment: I read in some threads here that the Mac NSViewController isn't really helping in.. anything, so I can just as easily do a NSView subview or am I wrong?

Comment: Erm... to do proper MVC (Model-View-Controller) design, you need to have both an NSView (your view layer) *and* some kind of controller object such as NSViewController. If you don't want to use NSViewController, you could just use an NSObject subclass as your controller layer, but you shouldn't go and put all your controller code in an NSView subclass. The pertinent rule is that a view object should never talk to the model (your data storage) directly.